# Creating a Swift Singleton with completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, callback, singleton, completionhandler

I am creating a singleton for use as a model in my app. The initialisation process includes an API call so I need to make use of a completion handler. The problem is that the private initialiser contains the completion handler which is instantiated using a public property. How do I add a completion handler to the get instance call to ensure the data has been loaded?

Here is the code so far with the API call missed to clarity.

```
import Foundation

struct Country {
    var name: String
    var region: String
    var subRegion: String
}

class Countries {

    var countryData = [Country]()

    // how do I call it?
    static let getInstance = Countries()

    private init(completionHandler: (Bool)) {
        // do some async stuff
        completionHandler(true)
    }

}

// this is how I envisage calling it from my controller.

Countries.getInstance(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
    // the data is available now so we can do stuff with it, such as making calls to extract specific data.
})
```

I'm probably over-complicating the process but need to be absolutely confident the data has been pulled from the API before trying to use the singleton.

Comment: Why do you want to put the async part into `init()`? When init completes, your object should be initialized correctly. Doing stuff asynchronously there seems strange.

Comment: Looking at the Swift init() syntax it seems that there is no point where I can return the object. Because I have an API call part of the initialisation process involves a completion handler so I need to wait for this to complete before I return the initialised object.

Comment: `init()` does not return the object, but is called between allocating the memory and actually using it. When it returns the object must be usable. You should try to refactor your code so that you do not have to do anything async within init. Either do your remote operations earlier and pass the result to your class or move these calls to some other method.

Comment: Thanks Tali. If I move the async call outside the class I break encapsulation and need to include this call in every view controller that might access the singleton. If I move the async call to another method in the class surely I'm just making the problem more abstract since I would need to use a callback to access this method from the initialiser so I know when the async task has finished? This feels like a flaw in Swift, it has been simple to achieve in other OOP languages such as Java and C++.

Comment: Then can't you just wait for completion of your async task within init()? In your example you tried to provide a completion handler when accessing your singleton, which is strange. Did you want to provide one handler per view controller?

Comment: Tali. That I think is the key question. I want to wait for the async task to complete within init but because the task is async, init return before the task has completed.